# Google App Engine (Java 11 Standard, basic_scaling) idle_timeout not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I have a Java Spring-Boot application deployed in an App Engine Java 11 Standard environment. 
My app.yaml config is very simple:

```
runtime: java11
env: standard
instance_class: B4

handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto

basic_scaling:
  idle_timeout: 3600s
  max_instances: 1
```

If I'm not mistaken this should keep an instance running for an hour before it shuts down. When I look at the logs I can see that a few minutes after the instance is created the /_ah/stop request is send and the instance shuts down:

```
2020-02-13T12:43:35.125504Z GET 200 95 B 23,3 s Unknown /_ah/start I GET 200 95 B 23,3 s
2020-02-13T12:43:45.590697Z   .   ____          _            __ _ _ A 
2020-02-13T12:43:45.590710Z  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \ A 
2020-02-13T12:43:45.591215Z ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \ A 
2020-02-13T12:43:45.591236Z  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) ) A 
2020-02-13T12:43:45.591251Z   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / / A 
2020-02-13T12:43:45.591266Z  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/ A 
2020-02-13T12:43:45.596711Z  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.3.RELEASE) A 
[...]
2020-02-13T12:50:34.948123Z GET 200 95 B 59 ms Unknown /_ah/stop A GET 200 95 B 59 ms
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the instance keep idling for at least 60 minutes? Am I doing something wrong here or is it a problem with Google App Engine?

Comment: Did your instance shutdown immediately after you received that request?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. And when I turn on the "/var/log/google_init.log" immediately afterwards it also logs: 

2020-02-13T12:50:35.495014Z [start] 2020/02/13 13:50:35.494065 Quitting on terminated signal 
2020-02-13T12:50:35.504274Z [start] 2020/02/13 13:50:35.503817 Start program failed: user application failed with exit code -1 (refer to stdout/stderr logs for more detail): signal: terminated 
2020-02-13T12:50:35.709105967Z Container called exit(1).